# Запросы к базе

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Есть база по автозапчастям со следующими столбцами:

```
id|number|made|part_name|oem
```

Сейчас нужно сделать поиск, чтобы можно было искать по одному критерию, или по всем сразу, или по нескольким.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что для каждого расклада (выбранного/ых пункта/ов) нужно писать отдельный запрос к базе данных?

То есть выбрал посетитель только made (марку машины), то запрос

```
("SELECT * FROM somenaw where made like=%$made%")
```

если выбрал made и part_name (наименование запчасти):

```
("SELECT * FROM somenaw where made like=%$made% AND part_name like=%$part_name%")
```

Это получается, для каждого отдельного случая нужно будет запросы писать или можно как-то более универсально сделать?!

Сорри за нубство.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По Вашей задаче:

```
$wh = array();
if($_POST['made'] != ''){
$wh[] = "'made like %".$_POST['made']."%'";
}
if($_POST['part_name'] != ''){
$wh[] = "'part_name like %".$_POST['part_name']."%'";
}
if($_POST['oem'] != ''){
$wh[] = "'oem like %".$_POST['oem']."%'";
}
if(count($wh) != 0){
   $where = ' where ';
   $where .= implode(' and ',$wh);
}
else{
   $where = '';
};
```

Дальше подставляем в запроc:

```
("SELECT * FROM somenaw ".$where);
```

Как-то так. Естественно, перед подстановкой переменных проверяйте их. Мало ли чего пришлют в запросе. Почитайте про [sql инъекция](https://www.google.com.ua/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=sql%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Был такой вариант, думал напишу скажут "велик изобретаю" ))

Comment: my god

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM somenaw';
    ...
    $params = array('made', 'part_name', 'oem',);
    $conditions = array();
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if ($_POST[$param]) {
            $conditions[] = sprintf("%s LIKE '%%%s%%'", $param, $_POST[$param]); // простите за процентное безумие
        }
    }
    if ($conditions) {
        $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
    }

Comment: Etki тоже вариант. Один и тот же результат можно реализовать разными способами)

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает условие WHERE динамически генерировать?

```
where = '1'
if made_param:
    where += ' AND made like %made_param%'
if year_param:
    where += ' AND year >= year_param'
```